# How to create a trigger that switches values of a composite type column

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin

I need to create a trigger that, when i update the value of a field on a column of a table it automatically puts the old value into another field of another composite type column
I tried this:

```
create or replace function valores_progresso_cliente()
returns trigger as $$
begin
update progresso_cliente set medida_antiga.med_antebraco = (medida_atual).med_antebraco, medida_atual.med_antebraco = (new.med_antebraco(medida_atual)) where rg_progresso_cliente = rg_progresso_cliente;
return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

I need to pass the rg_progresso_cliente  through the trigger each time i run the update

```
update progresso_cliente set medida_atual.med_antebraco = 8.00 where rg_progresso_cliente = '368242365';
```

but i cant figure out how
This is how my table progresso_cliente is:

```
create table progresso_cliente(rg_progresso_cliente primary key
                               medida_atual medidas,
                               medida_antiga medidas);
```

what i want to do is basically create a trigger that each time i run an update for example updating one of the fields from medida_atual its previously field get into medida_antiga field

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use composite types as table columns if I were you.

Anyway, the way to do this is a `BEFORE` trigger that does not `UPDATE`, but assign new values to `NEW`, something like

```
DECLARE
   swap_var double precision;
BEGIN
   swap_var := (NEW.medida_atual).med_antebraco;
   (NEW.medida_atual).med_antebraco := (NEW.medida_atual).medida_atual;
   (NEW.medida_atual).medida_atual := swap_var;

   RETURN NEW;
END;
```